# Preserve header in portrait location on landscape page

Tags: landscape

I'm using fancyhdr to include a header on a long document that includes both portrait and landscape pages. I'd like the header to show up in the portrait orientation on the landscape pages - instead of on the bottom right in the code below, I'd like it to stay on the top right. Does anybody know how to fore the portrait placement? Tex code is below.

```
\documentclass[10pt, letter]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\textcolor{gray}{Mock Draft}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\textbf{Example}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Thanks!